# CORS interfering with Spring Security oauth2

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm having problems trying to get a token from *oauth/token* from the browser. I have a Spring Boot application with Spring Security and Spring Security oauth, and I'm trying to authenticate from a javascript SPA in a different port.

When CORS is disabled in the backend, I can get tokens from the oauth endpoints no problem, using either Postman or the terminal, but I can't get them from javascript since the CORS preflight fails.

If I enable CORS, the preflight succeeds, but now I get an `InsufficientAuthenticationException` saying *"There's no client authentication. Try adding an appropriate authentication filter"*. From what I can gather, that's because Spring Security fails to get the principal from the request.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to deal with this?

Comment: When you are sending requests from other domain,CORS blocks the pre-flight request which is `OPTIONS`. So add `@CrossOrigin` and `@RestController` in your controller code and check once.

Comment: @Hema yeah, that's my problem, when I add CORS (on every endpoint) I get the `InsufficientAuthenticationException`. Should I add a `@RestController` containing the oauth endpoints that spring creates automatically, or would that override spring security?

Comment: No that would not over ride. Just add @RestController and try once.Which is working fine for me.So suggesting you

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Apparently the Oauth2 endpoints and filters get processed before getting to the Spring Security filter chain, so adding CORS filters normally wouldn't work, but adding a CORS filter bean with high order priority ended up working.

This is my dedicated configuration class for CORS (adapted from the official spring guide, I'll be tweaking it later)

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {
//IMPORTANT: it has to be a normal configuration class, 
//not extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter or other Spring Security class
    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean customCorsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));

        //IMPORTANT #2: I didn't stress enough the importance of this line in my original answer, 
        //but it's here where we tell Spring to load this filter at the right point in the chain
        //(with an order of precedence higher than oauth2's filters)
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using spring 4.3 version and your code shows error in my case like FilterRegistrationBean cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: @sireeshaj I basically haven't touched this code since posting it and it's still working. I just changed the method name one time from `corsFilter` to `customCorsFilter` because spring was complaining (since spring boot already defines its own bean with that name), maybe try that? Otherwise my code looks like the one above and runs fine on spring boot 1.5.12 (with spring 4.3.16)

Comment: I must have looked at at least 20 different "Answers" to this question that had several versions of your posted answer. Not a single one of them used bea,.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE) which was exactly my problem. It took me a couple hours to make it to your answer, but I sure am glad I found it. Thank you!

Comment: @spetz83 good catch, I had already forgotten about the importance of that detail, but it's the most critical part of the snippet really. I've updated the answer highlighting that fact, thanks

Comment: You Sir ! I too searched half the internet and finally. A big thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just an update of SrThompson's response if you are using Spring boot 2, the class `FilterRegistrationBean` is now generic.

So the code looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> customCorsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:3000");
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://production.url");
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));

        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }
}
```